# Rails API only with Stripe API integration error "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe...."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add Stripe to my little project. It's a Rails API only app, so no frontend for now. I'm getting this error when testing paying with a credit card.

> "Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see [https://stripe.com/docs/testing."](https://stripe.com/docs/testing.%22)

I understand I can't pass credit card details directly to the API but what I'm doing is passing that card info to the **Stripe::Token**, so it tokenize the card and then pass that to **Stripe::Charge** method.

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  validates :stripe_id, presence: true
  has_many :orders
  before_validation :create_on_stripe, on: :create

  def create_on_stripe
    params = { email: self.email, name: self.first_name }
    response = Stripe::Customer.create(params)
    pry
    self.stripe_id = response.id
  end
```

My order model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :credit_card_number, :credit_card_exp_month, :credit_card_exp_year, :credit_card_cvv
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :payment
  after_create :create_payment

  enum payment_method: %i[credit_card]
  def create_payment
    params = {
      order_id: id,
      credit_card_number: credit_card_number,
      credit_card_exp_month: credit_card_exp_month,
      credit_card_exp_year: credit_card_exp_year,
      credit_card_cvv: credit_card_cvv
    }
    Payment.create!(params)
  end
end
```

and the payment model:

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :credit_card_number, :credit_card_exp_month, :credit_card_exp_year, :credit_card_cvv
  belongs_to :order
  before_validation :create_on_stripe

  def create_on_stripe
    token = get_token
    params = { amount: order.amount_cents, currency: 'usd', source: token}
    response = Stripe::Charge.create(params)
    self.stripe_id = response.id
  end

  def get_token
    Stripe::Token.create({
      card: {
        number: credit_card_number,
        exp_month: credit_card_exp_month,
        exp_year: credit_card_exp_year,
        cvc: credit_card_cvv,
      }
    })
  end
end
```

The order controller is this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class OrdersController < Api::V1::ApiController
      include Pundit
      after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:create]
      def create
        @order = Order.new(order_params.merge(amount_cents: 500, payment_method: 'credit_card'))
        if @order.save
          render json: { order: @order, payment: @order.payment }, status: :created
        else
          render json: @response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
      private
      def order_params
        params.require(:data).permit(:user_id, :credit_card_number, :credit_card_exp_month, :credit_card_exp_year, :credit_card_cvv)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The postman request is the following, all these data gets to **get_token** method where it fails showing the mentioned error.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/orders
{
    "data": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "credit_card_number": "4000056655665556",
        "credit_card_exp_month": "12",
        "credit_card_exp_year": "2030",
        "credit_card_cvv": "123"
    }
}
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a clear question here, but I'll infer that it's "how can I do this"?

While you're sending to the token create API, this is still sending card details directly from your servers to Stripe's API, which has considerable [PCI compliance implications](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) (see "API direct" tab). Unless you are already PCI compliant, you should instead use [Stripe.js & Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/elements) to collect these details client-side directly from the customer without passing through your server.

If you are able to handle card details securely, you should [contact Stripe's support team](https://support.stripe.com/contact) for guidance.

Comment: According to stripe documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card I can create a token like this, am I wrong?

Comment: You can, yes, but as I said you're still sending card details to the API directly from your server using a secret key, which is the issue here. Instead, you can create the token using Stripe.js from the client-side using your publishable key and Elements. Even better would be using Payment Methods, the current API pattern for payment details collection.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/finalize-payments-on-the-server?platform=web&type=setup#create-pm

Or without 3DS support: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-card-without-authentication?platform=web#add-elements-to-your-page

Comment: @NolanH and what if you don't have access to Stripe.js or Elements?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by not having access to Stripe.js? Ultimately if you want to send raw card details to the API you have to talk to Stripe's support team.